# rails unexpected text node at bottom of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am running this view

```
    <header>
    <h1 class="h2">Users</h1>
</header>

<section class="search-form">
    <form>
        <%= form_for :users, method: :get do |f| %>
            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                <%= label_tag   :keywords, nil, class: "sr-only" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :keywords, nil, placeholder: "Search for first name, last name or email address", class: "form-control input-sm"%>
                <span class="input-group-btn"><%= submit_tag "Find", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
                </span>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </form>
    <!-- <h4 class="searchedFor"> <small>Searched for: to be added</small></h4>-->
</section>


<section class="search-results">
    <header><h3>Results</h3></header>
    <ol class="list-group">
        <%= @users.each do |user| %>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <h3 class="pull-right"><small class="text-uppercase">created </small><%= user.created_at.to_time %></h3>
                <h2 class="h3"><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %><small> <%= user.username %></small></h2>
                <%= link_to "Show", users_path(@user), class: "pull-right" %>
                <h4><%= user.email %></h4>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
</section>
```

While the search and form function ok for the rest, my page renders with a text node (see screenshot) at the bottom and I have no clue as to why???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the erb blocks around your `loops` from `<%=` to `<%`.  Otherwise you're going to print the enumerator itself to the screen, like you are now.

From:

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
```

To:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```